# Can someone explain how callbacks are invoked in Node.js please?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I understand callback functions conceptually, but I don't understand how they are understand in Node.js and am quite confused by the syntax. Can someone give me a simple explanation for each line of code which is running? The code works, but I don't understand why.

```
var removeById = function(personId, done) {
  Person.findByIdAndRemove(personId, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      done(err); 
    }
    done(null, data);
 });
};
```

Line by line explanation.

Comment: Related: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html , where I try to explain what callback functions are. *"I understand callback functions conceptually, but I don't understand how they are understand in Node.js"* A callback is just a function that is passed to another function and usually not called by yourself. That is not different in Node, so there is nothing else you should have to know. What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: The code you've included doesn't seem to be complete-- `done` is never defined.  Callbacks in Node.js aren't, to my knowledge, written any differently nor execute any differently than would a callback pattern executing in browser-based JavaScript.  You may consider reviewing [ask] and considering rephrasing this question to make it clearer what exactly it is that you are confused by, and how you think it is that Node.js callbacks differ from other JS callback patterns.

Comment: Your code sample is incomplete as `done` is not declared.  Moreover, the declaration for the `findByIdAndRemove()` function appears to be missing. Please revise.

Answer (score 0):

**Line 1** (assume)

`var removeById = function(personId, done) {`

`done` is the formal identifier for `callback` that you'll pass later when you call `removeById` function

**Line 2**

`Person.findByIdAndRemove(personId, function(err, data) {`

`findByIdAndRemove` expects 2nd parameter to be a function with two parameters, first `err`, this will hold error and 2nd `data`, this will hold data/result

**Line 4**

`done(err)`

**Line 6**

Call your callback with error

`done(null, data)`

call your callback with first parameter as `null` (probably intended to signal there is no error) and `data` which would hold the data/result

Extra note:

The callback you pass to `removeById` should also (preferably, if you're not doing anything else with it) expect 2 parameters, same as callback passed to `findByIdAndRemove`

Comment: Cheers! Makes sense now!

Comment: You could accept the answer if it answered your query! (:

Answer (score 0):

The `Person.findByIdAndRemove` is basically something like :

```
Person.findByIdAndRemove = function(personId, callback) {
  // The code is executed 
  // call function on error | success
  callback(err, data);
};
```

The callback you want to execute should be something like:

```
const done = function(err, data) {
  if(err) {
   console.log(err); 
  }
  console.log(data);
}
```

Your code :

```
var removeById = function(personId, done) {
  Person.findByIdAndRemove(personId, function(err, data) {
    if(err) {
      done(err); 
    }
    done(null, data);
 });
};
```

Usage:

```
removeById(3, done);
```